# 'mocha' is not recognized as an internal or external command - mocha not getting automatically installed with supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js, supertest

I need to unit-test my rest api written in NodeJS. For this, I need to use [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) npm package. I was following [this tutorial article](https://hackernoon.com/api-testing-using-supertest-1f830ce838f1) for implementing the unit test functionality.

Now, in this article it is mentioned that `mocha` is already included in `supertest` itself, so there's no need to install it separately. So, I only install `supertest` using - `npm install --save-dev supertest`.

But, when I add this line in my `package.json` - `"test": "mocha"`, and run `npm test`, it gives error saying `'mocha' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I need to run `npm install --save-dev mocha` to make it run successfully. But why do I need to include `mocha` separately and if that's how it is supposed to run, why is it not mentioned in this article or on npm homepage of `supertest`?

Comment: Mohit - See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219034/nodemon-mocha-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable helps

Comment: Thanks @VimalMahi I checked this thread but unfortunately couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went to [Supertest page on npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) and checked the dependencies. Mocha is listed as a dev dependency. it means Mocha was used while creating supertest, but is not required for supertest to function.
When I work on Node.js project, I install certain packages as dev dependencies. These could be packages for testing (Mocha) or linting (Standard). What it means is when the project is deployed, it will not need these packages to function.

Also, you can use `npm list` command to see which modules are installed. I just installed supertest and ran npm list. This is structure of supertest :

[image]
As you can see Mocha is not listed

Further, ran `npm ls mocha` and output is:
`$ npm ls mocha
   nodetest@1.0.0 E:\Nodetest
   -- (empty)`

and when I ran `npm ls supertest`, output is:
`$ npm ls supertest
  nodetest@1.0.0 E:\Nodetest
-- supertest@3.3.0`

Why sis the article say mocha is available? may be in an earlier version of supertest it was included as a dependency

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts @Sansolo. So, that means I need to install `mocha` as well for running test cases with supertest, right? I am a little confused as on their npm page also, they are using `mocha` syntax but there isn't mention of installing it separately, but may be that's obvious.

Comment: @Mohit Bharadwaj I checked the article and it does say supertest includes mocha.  Well, may be previous versions did. Can you please mark this as answer? :)