# nodemon cannot recognize mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, package.json, nodemon

I tried to run test automatically using nodemon instead of running them manually. I installed mocha and nodemonn on single time. This is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "Ti Ri Ho",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nodemon --exec 'mocha -R min'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.15",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7"
  }
}
```

I change  `"scripts": {"test": "mocha" }` to "scripts": `{"test": "nodemon --exec 'mocha -R min'"}`.What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Why `nodemon`? Mocha has watch flag `mocha -w`.

Comment: But if you do need to use nodemon for some reason you could try `nodemon --exec './node_modules/.bin/mocha -R min'`

Comment: I know we can use --watch because --watch sometimes has a little bit of iffy functionality or compatibility with mongoose so instead  i m making use of nodemon. It will start mocha each time.

Comment: it didn't worked for me

Comment: tried google again...find solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219034/nodemon-mocha-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable) `"nodemon --exec \"mocha -R min\""`